# Angular 2 create a library extract css

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building a big components library for our application. Regarding the styles - I saw this is the best practice, when talking about Angular libs - to inline the templates and the styles.

But in my case, I really want to extract the whole styles into one `bundle.css` file and require it in my application so I can benefit from the browser cache.

Tools like ng-packager are inline the external SCSS files, how can I do this?